# SQL Functionality in Excel VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

For those who don't know, it is fairly easy to add SQL functionality to VBA macros. The following article provides the code: http://analystcave.com/excel-using-sql-in-vba-on-excel-data/

I modified this a bit (happy to provide the code) so that it outputs nicely and put it in a Sub that I can call. This saves me from having to do multiple sorts, copy paste, etc. to find specific data from a large worksheet.

Note a problem, however, when working with the workbook from an online source e.g. Gmail:

> .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";"

This works fine when the file is saved to a drive, but from an online site, Excel can't connect. Any suggestions on modifying the connection string for when the file isn't saved anywhere?

Comment: Can you provide a sample ConnectionString in that case?  You may need to manipulate it for it to work.

Comment: You cannot use this approach if the workbook isn't saved to disk.  Best you could do is save a temporary copy to disk and query that.

Comment: @wdosanjos The current connection string uses ThisWorkbook.Path and .Name, but what to do if the file isn't saved and thus doesn't have a path?

Comment: Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 requires a file, so until you save the file it will not work.

Comment: @wdosanjos Okay, so there's no way to point to the file in memory or anything like that?

Comment: Unfortunately no, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's interested, this code (based on the code from Analyst Cave) works great for using SQL in VBA. Save the following as a Sub:

```
Option Explicit

Sub QuerySQL(result_location As Range, query As String)

    Dim ResultWS As Worksheet
    Set ResultWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Query Results")
    ResultWS.Cells.ClearContents

    If query = "" Then Exit Sub

    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object
    'Add to the workbook a database connection with itself
    'Note other ConnectionString could be used to access a variety of media
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With

    'Build and execute the SQL query
    Set rs = cn.Execute(query)
    If rs.EOF = True Then Exit Sub

    'Print column labels
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        result_location.Offset(0, i).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

    'Print column contents
    i = 0
    Do
        For j = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            result_location.Offset(i + 1, j).Value = rs.Fields(j).Value
        Next j

        rs.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until rs.EOF

    'Close the connections
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

To use it, simply do the following:

```
Dim myQuery As String
myQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]"
Call QuerySQL(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), myQuery)
```

It uses MS Access style SQL. The above will look to Sheet2 as the table and print the result starting in A1 on Sheet1.

Comment: This doesn't appear to address the issue raised in the question.  (And if you used `result_location.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs` to store the data, you would improve the speed dramatically.)

Comment: Just thought I'd add it as there are others asking how to add SQL to Excel and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: It shouldn't be added as an answer if it doesn't answer the question - it should be added as part of the question, but in this case it doesn't really need to be as you already had a good MCVE.